# Align Objects: Align Mode

Tags: objects, transforms

This operator has several options. The one I'm having questions with is `Align Mode -> Positive Sides/Negative Sides`

In the manual it states this:

> `Align Mode.` The Align Mode control will define what part of the objects will be aligned:

> `Positive Sides/Negative Sides.`
> The positive or negative sides (on the global axes) of their respective bounding boxes.

What does `Positive Sides/Negative Sides` do? Where can I get the information about these `Object Bounding Box Sides`?